# Query Is Not Summing As I Need

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am trying to write a CTE Query and I am way before a "New" title for CTE Queries.  But I feel I am fairly close to getting the end game that I am after.  My query works perfect until I throw in the CTE and even after including the CTE it still works perfect just gives each individual instance as opposed to the SUM like I need.  What should I alter in my syntax so that the query only produces the SUM as I need?

```
;With CTE 
As
(
  SELECT 
    BadgeNum
    ,NameOnFile
    ,SUM((CONVERT(decimal(18,6),pyrll.hoursworked))) AS [Hours]
  FROM 
    masterpayroll pyrll
  Group By
    BadgeNum,NameOnFile
)
SELECT
,SUM(pyrll.[Hours]) As [Hours Worked This Week]
,pyrll.NameOnFile As [Employee Name]
,COUNT(case when pf.arrest_status in ('Final', 'Complete',) And pf.supervisorSignoff IS NOT NULL   THEN pf.ID else null end)
,COUNT(case when pf.arrest_status in ('Pending', 'Incomplete', 'On Hold') THEN pf.ID else null end)
FROM personelFiles pf
INNER JOIN CTE pyrll
ON pf.ID = pyrll.BadgeNum
WHERE pf.officerName Like 'Gat%'
GROUP BY pyrll.[Employee Name], pyrll.[Hours Worked This Week]
```

EDIT ---Top Data Set is what is returned from query - bottom data set is what I want to see returned.
[image]

EDIT # 2 - If their is a better way to write the query to still produce the desired result of the 2nd data set in my image below I am up for that as well!

Comment: what exactly you need? Can you be more specific or provide sample output?

Comment: @EduardUta - Image included.  Top result is what query includes, bottom result set is what I want it to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have aggregate column alias name in the group by, you need only the employee name

Change your group by clause from

```
    GROUP BY pyrll.[Employee Name], pyrll.[Hours Worked This Week]
```

To

```
    GROUP BY pyrll.NameOnFile
```

Comment: altering my Group By statement to what you have above still produces individual results.

Comment: @UGh, yes type.  Updating initial post now.

Comment: @user2676140, the group by should fix, i don't think of any thing else wrong. also i changed to nameoffile instead of employee name.